# g++: fatal error: ‘-fuse-linker-plugin’, but liblto_plugin.so not found

Tags: gcc, compiler-errors

Recently I compiled the gcc on local machine with configure && make && make install.
I want to use the brand-new gcc to do some simple code like compiling hello_world program, however it throws the error

```
./g++ /tmp/helloworld.cpp -o helloworld -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/9 -I/usr/include/c++/9/ -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/ -llto_plugin.so --verbose -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/ -llto_plugin
```

> g++: fatal error: ‘-fuse-linker-plugin’, but liblto_plugin.so not
> found

Why does the options `-L` failed in the g++ command?

I compared the output with --verbose between system-gcc and my-gcc, mostly on the COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS

// system-gcc

> /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/collect2 -plugin
> /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/liblto_plugin.so
> -plugin-opt=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/lto-wrapper -plugin-opt=-fresolution=/tmp/ccRwG4o2.res -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_s -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_s -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc --build-id --eh-frame-hdr -m elf_x86_64 --hash-style=gnu --as-needed -dynamic-linker
> /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -pie -z now -z relro -o /tmp/helloworld
> /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o
> /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o
> /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/crtbeginS.o
> -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9 -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../lib -L/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/lib/../lib -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/../lib -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../.. /tmp/ccicG70Z.o -lstdc++ -lm -lgcc_s -lgcc -lc -lgcc_s -lgcc
> /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/crtendS.o
> /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crtn.o

// my-gcc

> COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-o' 'helloworld' '-I'
> '/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/9' '-I' '/usr/include/c++/9/'
> '-L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/' '-v'
> '-L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/' '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=generic'
> '-march=x86-64'

And what's more, i also tried the -f-no-use-linker-plugin, but it gave another error.

```
[1] % ./g++ /tmp/helloworld.cpp -o helloworld -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/9 -I/usr/include/c++/9/ -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/ -llto_plugin.so --verbose -fno-use-linker-plugin
```

> ~/GCC-12.2.0/libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/12.2.0/collect2
> --eh-frame-hdr -m elf_x86_64 -dynamic-linker /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -o helloworld
> /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o
> /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o
> /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/crtbegin.o
> -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/ -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../lib/../lib64 -L/lib/../lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/lib/../lib/../lib64 -L/usr/lib/../lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/../lib/../lib64 -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../lib64 -L/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/lib/../lib64 -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/../lib64 -L/home/xx/GCC-12.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/12.2.0 -L/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/lib/../lib64 -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/../lib64 -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9 -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../lib -L/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/lib/../lib -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/../lib -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../.. -L/home/xx/GCC-12.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/12.2.0/../../.. /tmp/ccZKcOFK.o -llto_plugin.so -lstdc++ -lm -lgcc_s -lgcc -lc -lgcc_s
> -lgcc /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/crtend.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crtn.o
> /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llto_plugin.so

Then what happend. Thanks.